# Why is $\frac{\sqrt {-h}}{h}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ - h}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sqrt h}{h}=h^{0.5}\cdot h^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt h}\,.$$

$$\text{Why is}\,\frac{\sqrt{ -h}}{h}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ - h}}\,?$$

Excuse me for my stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are getting at is the additive powers of exponents.  $a^xa^y = a^{x+1}$ so $h^{.05}h^{1} = h^{-.5} = \frac 1{\sqrt{h}}$

So $\frac{\sqrt{-h}}{h} = (-h)^{.5}*h = -(-h)^{.5}(-h) =-(-h)^{.5}(-h)^1= - (-h)^{-.5} = - \frac {1}{\sqrt{-h}}$.

Comment: Please make correction of mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

> $$\text{Why is}\,\frac{\sqrt{ -h}}{h}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ - h}}\,?$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{ -h}}{h}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{ -h}}{\sqrt{ -h}}=\frac{h(-1)}{h\sqrt{ -h}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-h}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write $\sqrt {-h} $ , it means that
$h\leq 0$

so
$h=-(-h)=-\sqrt {-h}\sqrt {-h}$

and if $h <0$,

$$\frac {\sqrt {-h}}{h}=\frac {-1}{\sqrt {-h}} . $$

Comment: Unless we are working in complex numbers.